# REST API using Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, jersey, hk2

I would like to implement a REST API using Jersey 2 and I would like to have resources separated into interfaces and their implementations like e.g.:

```
@Path("hello")
public interface HelloLogic {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String hello();
}

public class HelloLogicResource implements HelloLogic {
    public String hello() {
        return "{\"reply\": \"Hello\"}";
    }
}
```

I do not have any luck getting the resources exposed though. For the hello resource just mentioned I was hoping that the following would be enough:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new MyApplicationBinder());
    }
}

public class MyApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(HelloLogic.class).to(HelloLogicResource.class);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>stines.api.MyApplication</param-value> 
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But when hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

I get a 404 response:

[image]

Input will be greatly appreciated :) Thanks.

---

**New discovery:** it works with this:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        registerClasses(HelloLogicResource.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        registerClasses(HelloLogicResource.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1:** You need to tell Jersey where your resources are:

```
public MyApplication() {
    packages("stines.api.resources");
    register(new MyApplicationBinder());
}
```

I believe in this case you want to use the package where HelloLogic lives, but you can also add multiple packages if needed:

```
public MyApplication() {
    packages("stines.api.resources;stines.api.resources.impl");
    register(new MyApplicationBinder());
}
```

**Edit 2:** removed note about backwards Guice binding

Comment: Updated my answer, I think you are also missing a call to `packages`.

Comment: It seems to work with the simpler MyApplication I have just added at the bottom of my question. I get the warning "Component of class interface stines.api.HelloLogic cannot be instantiated and will be ignored" if I try to register HelloLogic.

Comment: It works with the MyApplication added at the end of my question, yes :) It didn't work when I tried to register HelloLogic like you suggested.