# Jersey with spring boot class/interface cannot be instantiated and will be ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, jersey-2.0

I have a spring-boot web application, i am trying to use jersey for its REST calls.

Once maven build is done, i can deploy it using jboss. But when i try to hit the url (using postman), i get the following message:

```
" WARNING [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator] (default task-1) Component of class interface com.xyz.abcInter cannot be instantiated and will be ignored"
```

Jersey config code:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{
    public JerseyConfig()
    {
    packages("com.xyz");    
    register(abcInter.class);
    }
}
```

"abcInter" (an interface) code:

```
@Path("/hi/hello")
public interface abcInter {
      @GET
      @Path("/there")
      @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
      public String getName() throws Exception; 
}
```

"abc" class implementing "abcInter" code:

```
   @Component
    public class abc implements abcInter
    {
        @Override
        public String getName() throws Exception
        {
            return "{\"name\": {\"nitish\": \"kashyap\",\"chinmoy\": \"das\"}}";
        }
    }
```

> IMPORTANT: I have in other projects registered interfaces in the same
>   way and they seemed to work. Like in the [example here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/)
>   if you change the annotations from that in the class to an interface (structured as in this question), it works. (adding @Component or @ Named at class does the work)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564142/rest-api-using-jersey-2

Comment: @user7294900, i have tried the verified answer of that post. Sadly, doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: The `@Path` goes on the concrete class (`abc`), not the interface, and you don't register the interface, you register the concrete class.

Comment: yes @PaulSamsotha, but i want the jax-rs annotations to be in the interface itself. It is possible actually, if you see [this linked](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/) example, and modify the sourcecode to a similar structure as the question i posted, i'll work just fine. i wanted to know the possible reasons why it could fail like in this case of mine.

Comment: Only `@Path` needs to be on the concrete class.

Comment: _"I have in other projects registered interfaces in the same way and they seemed to work. Though none of them were in spring-boot. They were in jersey alone."_ - I highly doubt it. Double check.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, take [this example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/) and change the annotations from the class to an interface (structure it like the original question of this post). It seems to work fine. I'd like to apologize as i might be wrong but this example should work fine.

Comment: Yes you are wrong. I consider myself somewhat of an expert in this framework and I know the rules. The `@Path` on the interface is ignored. It must be on the concrete class. Look at it this way. If you just register an interface, how is Jersey supposed to know what classes implements that interface? It's impossible. There is absolutely no way to find out what classes implement a specific interface.

Comment: Okay. But then what is the reason as to how [the example here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/) when modified as per the question posted works ? I am really confused :(

Comment: adding @Component or @ Named at class does the work

Comment: hey @PaulSamsotha, i tired making two classes implement a same interface, it seems like if i register the interface in the config file and put annotations like @ Named on either of the class, that class will be registered. If i put on both or in neither, i get this error of not finding constructor. (all done w.r.t [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/))